# In solidity, how can I hardcode bytes > 32 bytes

Tags: solidity, bytes, memory

I want to create a contract with a hardcoded bytes variable.

```
contract Test(){
   function Test(){
      bytes x = 0x..... //greater than 32 bytes 
   }
}
```

The above returns a `Type int_const not implicitly convertible to expected type bytes storage pointer` error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
contract C1 {
    function f1() returns(bytes) {
        bytes memory bb = "\x00\x01\x02";  // you can extend this
        return(bb);
    }
}
```

Tested using online Solidity Browser, output is:

```
Result: "0x000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000030001020000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
Cost: 25630 gas.
```

Comment: whats strange is it works with 0x000102, but crashes with 0x0001a2...

Comment: Opened up an issue: https://github.com/chriseth/browser-solidity/issues/114